# generate inverted index in python

Tags: python, mapreduce

Hi there Im new at python and I want to study about Hadoop Mapreduce. I have an data like this

```
Vancouver-1 35.5
Vancouver-2 34.6
Vancouver-3 37.6
```

That shows the state-month and the maximum temperature
So I want to make a inverted data like this

```
35 Vancouver-2
36 Vancouver-2 Vancouver-1
37 Vancouver-2 Vancouver-1
38 Vancouver-2 Vancouver-1 Vancouver-3
```

The number is D degree from 10 and up to 50, next part is the list of the state that have equal or below D degree

my mapper files:

```
%%writefile mapper.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import math

QueryMaxTemp = 50;

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    lfields = line.split('\t');
    city_month = lfields[0];
    maxtemp = math.ceil(float(lfields[1]));
for i in QueryMaxTemp:// I think this is wrong
    print ('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(i,city_month,maxtemp))
```

my reducer files

```
%%writefile reducer.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def emit(maxtemp, city_month_list):
    print('{}\t{}'.format(maxtemp,city_month_list))

last_maxtemp = ''
last_city_month_list = ''
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    maxtemp, city_month_lists = line.split('\t', 1)
    if last_maxtemp == maxtemp:
        last_city_month_list = last_city_month_list + max(maxtemp, last_maxtemp) // I think this is wrong
    else:
        if last_maxtemp:
            emit(last_maxtemp, last_city_month_list)
        last_maxtemp = maxtemp
        last_city_month_list = city_month_lists

if last_maxtemp:
        emit(last_maxtemp, last_city_month_list)
```

I try to fix it but no idea, any idea to solve that ? I want to make a inverted data like the sample below. Thanks

Comment: do you want to divide data based on max temp?

Comment: Yes, because I want to make a list of degree that based on maximum max temp, I want to list the state that have equal or below temperature from D degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use dict to sort the data. the key will be the maximum temperature and then append data(city month) to list.

```
res_dict = {}
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    lfields = line.split('\t')
    city_month = lfields[0]
    maxtemp = math.ceil(float(lfields[1]))
    if maxtemp not in res_dict:
        res_dict[maxtemp] = []
    res_dict[maxtemp].append(city_month)
for maxtemp, city_month in res_dict.iteritems()
    print ('\t{}\t{}'.format(city_month,maxtemp))




import sys

def emit(res_dict):
    for maxtemp, city_month in res_dict.iteritems()
       print ('\t{}\t{}'.format(city_month,maxtemp))

res_dict
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    maxtemp, city_month_lists = line.split('\t', 1)
    if maxtemp not in res_dict:
        res_dict[maxtemp] = []
    res_dict[maxtemp].append(city_month)

emit(res_dict)
```

Comment: In reducer file I got loop, it get the same data like this: 35 Vancouver-1 Vancouver-1 Vancouver-1

Answer (score 0):

sorry, now that's reduce

```
import math

data = """Vancouver-1 35.5
Vancouver-2 34.6
Vancouver-3 37.6"""

lines = data.split('\n')
mapped_data = list()
for line in lines:
    city_month, maxtemp = line.split()
    maxtemp = math.ceil(float(maxtemp))
    mapped_data.append([city_month, maxtemp])

sorted_data = sorted(mapped_data, key=lambda x: x[1])

res = ''
cities_str = ''
for temp in range(10, 51):
    if sorted_data and sorted_data[0][1] < temp:
        cities_str += sorted_data.pop(0)[0]+' '
    res += str(temp)+' '+cities_str+'\n'

print(res)
```

Comment: The data is from a file and I need to use map reduce to do it.